# How could I put these lines in range format?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a text file with 826,838 lines. [Text file looks like this](https://image.ibb.co/dZhie5/Capture.png) (sorry, couldn't get the image uploader to work).

I'm using sed (sed -n '2p;$p') to print the second and last line but can't figure out how to put the lines in range format.

Current output:

```
     1    3008.00   7380.00  497724.00  3158482.00  497724.00   3158482.00
826838    4744.00   7409.00  480729.00  3207718.00  480729.00   3207718.00
```

Desired output:

```
1-826838  3008.00-4744.00  7380.00-7409.00  497724.00-480729.00  3158482.00-3207718.00  497724.00-480729.00  3158482.00-3207718.00
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Maybe saving each value in a var (with cut and grep), then concatenate variables, and finally printing the result. But it sounds barbaric, so I won't post it as a relevant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With single ***awk*** expression (will get the needed lines and make the needed ranges):

```
awk 'NR==2{ split($0,a) }END{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("%s\t",a[i]"-"$i); print "" }' file
```

The output:

```
1-826838    3008.00-4744.00 7380.00-7409.00 497724.00-480729.00 3158482.00-3207718.00   497724.00-480729.00 3158482.00-3207718.00
```

Comment: Thank you sir. This is great.

Comment: so the name of that text file is: "MP6060_Line_Section_1728P2-078-After_Merge_0001.trhdr". I'm trying to add it at the beginning of the output. What would be the best way to do this? Thanks again for your help

Comment: @c47v3770 You can prepend a BEGIN Section: `BEGIN{print "MP6060_Line_Section_1728P2-078-After_Merge_0001.trhdr"} `

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, you didn't understand clear: it should be `NR==2` cause the initial file is *a text file with 826,838 lines.* and it should *print the **second** and last line*. Besides, I wish you don't edit my answers

Comment: Apologies my mistake, didn't understand it. For editing will take care in future, not to touch.

Comment: `END{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s-%s%s", a[i], $i, (i<NF?OFS:ORS) }` would use the `OFS` value as intended without hard-coding a separator and it would avoid printing a trailing tab at the end of the line. Also, that will only work in some awks since POSIX doesn't guarantee that $0, $1, etc of the last record are still populated in the `END` section, only `NF`, so for portability across awks you need: `awk 'NR==2{split($0,a)} {split($0,b)} END{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s-%s%s", a[i], b[i], (i<NF?OFS:ORS) }'` file

Comment: @ RomanPerekhrest @Ed Morton thank you for your help. How would you add the name of the file at the beginning of the output?

Comment: @c47v3770, add `print FILENAME; ` before the `for` loop

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest OK that's what I did. Now I'm trying to figure out how to keep it all in a single line.

Comment: `printf("%s ", FILENAME); `

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '2H;$!d;H;x;:a;s/\n\s*(\S+)\s*(.*\n)\s*(\S+\s*)/\1-\3\n\2/;ta;P;d' file
```

Store line 2 and the last line in the hold space (HS). Following the last line, swap to the HS and then repeatedly move the first fields of the second and third lines to the first line. Finally print the first line only.

Comment: Thanks for your help.